# Can't access ClickOnce Data directory when not network deployed

Tags: .net, deployment, windows-7, clickonce, appdomain

I'm testing my clickonce deployment (WPF, .Net 4) and I can't seem to access the data directory. The application is installed and can run offline so I need a way to access the data directory when !ApplicationDeployment.IsNetworkDeployed

My manifest is correct and the data file is marked as such. The file is indeed copied to the Data directory in C:\Users\MyUserAccount\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0\Data...   (Windows 7)

I've tried:

```
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData)
```

and

```
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData)
```

... both functions return nothing and do not throw any errors. I can retrieve the BaseDirectory of the application but that doesn't help me getting the data file.

The data file is [posdm.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa459292%28v=winembedded.11%29.aspx). A POS for .Net utility program I need so that I can set defaults on hardware connected to the POS machine. I just need to figure out how to access it from the installed data directory.

**Edit**

Seems like its related to the separate AppDomain I create. It's not pulling in the ApplicationDeployment properties from the main AppDomain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had pass the applications main AppDomain variables to the separate AppDomain I created. The AppDomain I created didn't have the same values as the main AppDomain:

```
ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment.DataDirectory
ApplicationDeployment.IsNetworkDeployed
```